# ${0##/} works outside a function but does not work in a function

Tags: string, bash

```sh
SCRIPT="${0##}"  #works it strips off the path and returns the name of the shell script
echo "Script $script"

getVar(){
    SCRIPT="${0##/}"  #does not strip off the path it returns the $0 value
    echo "Script $script"
}

getVar
```

Comment: Did you mean `SCRIPT="${0##*/}"` and `echo "Script $SCRIPT"`?? Linux is case-sensitive... (note use lowercase variables for user-variables, generally uppercase are used for environment-variables)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please proof your script at https://www.shellcheck.net first.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Debugging questions require a [mre], but you're missing the input (`$0`) and output. But as @David said, this looks like a typo/misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

You have fundamental typos (or misconceptions) about the *parameter expansion* that trims from the left to the last occurrence of `'/'`. You script needs to be:

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT="${0##*/}"           # missing "*/" as part of expansion
echo "Script $SCRIPT"       # $SCRIPT must be uppercase

getVar(){
    SCRIPT="${0##*/}"       # missing the "*" as part of expansion
    echo "Script $SCRIPT"
}

getVar
```

A quick summary of *parameter expansions with substring removal* are:

```
${var#pattern}     Strip shortest match of pattern from front of $var
${var##pattern}    Strip longest match of pattern from front of $var
${var%pattern}     Strip shortest match of pattern from back of $var
${var%%pattern}    Strip longest match of pattern from back of $var
```

Where the pattern can include globs like `'*'` for matching any number of characters. So `${var##*/}` removes all characters from the beginning (front) of `var` up to and including the last `'/'`.